# cannot be opened because it is version 852

Tags: c#, sql

Создал проект в VS17, добавил станадртный сервер(Express):
[image: Версия sql]

Подключил его:
[image: подключение бд]

Проверил на наличие экземпляра:
[image: экземпляр]
Сделал установочник через VS installer project:
[image: установочник]
Стоит почему то версия 2012

Поставил на виртуальную машину с windows 7, запустил, появилось окно ошибок версий:
[image: ошибка версий]

Загрузил SqlServer 2016, той же версии что и на исходной машине, проверил экземпляры, они отсутствуют:
[image: отсутствие экземпляра]
Добавил 2016 версию в установочник:
[image]

Выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по вопросу вы не используете специфичных фич для конкретной версии, иначе бы знали, а используете вполне стандартный набор из ANSI-92/MSSQL2005+. В этом случае я предлагаю попробовать проделать следующее: в свойствах базы выставить уровень совместимости 100 и попробовать, будет ли работать. Если будет - то не устанавливать вообще SQL вместе с продуктом, а просто описать в требованиях минимальную версию сервера и редакцию и зафиксировать уровень совместимости БД. В остальном же - как-то сумбурно описано, не очень понятно на какой машине из каких инсталлеров ставилось и не/работает.

Comment: а все я нашел версия бд действительно 13.0.4001

Comment: только не понимаю как поставить на машину, 11 версии создается экземпляр а 13 нет

Comment: mssqllocaldb i mssqllocaldb показвает только 11

Comment: Вероятно вам лучше отредактировать вопрос, если у вас появилась новая информация и часть вопросов стали неактуальными и появились новые. Вопрос касается установки какой-то конкретной версии на конкретную операционную систему если уже установлен один инстанс?

Comment: готово, отредактировал

Comment: видимо не помогло

Comment: [SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper](https://github.com/igormf/SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper) - после установки должен появиться пункт с Sql Server 2016 в списке Необходимые компоненты.

Comment: я его поставил отдельно не работает

Comment: просто установил